# Understand itemBuilder: in AnimatedList (Flutter)

Tags: android, ios, flutter, dart

I want to add an animated list to my Flutter application I've been looking at a bunch of tutorials and they all use this syntax to crate an item builder function -
[image]

The code is working but I still don't understand a few things.

1. From where the animation and index came I did not declared them nor initialized them with any value ?
2. What increments the index ?
3. What makes the code iterate over the entire list ?

Maybe I'm just being a rookie not understating Dart or Flutter well enough but I would really apricate some help clarifying this subject.

Answer (score 0):

`itemBuilder` is a property defined as follow in the constructor of `AnimatedList`:

```dart
final AnimatedListItemBuilder itemBuilder;
```

And `AnimatedListItemBuilder` is a type defined like this:

```dart
typedef AnimatedListItemBuilder =
  Widget Function(BuildContext context, int index, Animation<double> animation);
```

So basically `itemBuilder` is a method which could be compared to a `build` method in a widget. Its purpose is to define how a defined number of items will be build.

Now to answer your three questions:

1. `animation` and `index` are internal variables defined inside `SliverAnimatedListState`. It is a `State` of `SliverAnimatedList` which is the widget used to render `AnimatedList` under the hood. As you might already expect `index` is the index of the item to build and `animation` is the animation applied to the widget.
2. The `index` increments itself automatically based on the parameter `initialItemCount`. Basically there is an internal variable which will decrement itself until it reaches 0 to build the correct number of items.
3. I think I've already answered to this question with 2). It iterates for each decrementation of `itemCount` until it reaches 0 and will call `itemBuilder` to render the widget.